# Python bubblesort with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, bubble-sort

I am new in Python and I am trying to implement an algorithm with bubblesort but using list comprenhension. Although I have used list comprenhension using if and for, I could not figure out a way to implement a nested for, as well as the swap for the sorting.

Below is the code I have tried to use.

```
import random as rn
l=[]
N=int(input('Give an integer: '))
for i in range(N):
    l.append(rn.randint(1,100))
print(l)

listset = [l[:k-1] + [l[k]] + [l[k-1]] + l[k+1:] if l[k] > l[k-1] else l for k in range(1,len(l)) ]

print(listset)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to use correctly list comprehension in order to implement the bubblesort algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's a practical goal.  Most sorting algorithms depend in the partial result to achieve the next step, which isn't really compatible with list comprehensions.

Comment: You might use [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/83763/138213) code to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Unfortunatelly, this a requirement of a short project that I am working on for a course and we are explicitly asked to use list comprehension for the bubblesort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is basically is bubble up the smallest (for ascending order) values to top in the list which is achieved in time `O(n^2)`.

In case of list comprehension, as we are creating new list I don't think exact in-place number swapping bubble sort algorithm is achievable. Though creating a new list by picking up smallest(ascending order) number from the unsorted list `n` times. Eventually it will create similar algorithm selection sort as following-

```
def extractMin(numberList):
   minValue = min(numberList)
   numberList.remove(minValue)
   return minValue

import random as rn
l=[]
N=int(input('Give an integer: '))
for i in range(N):
    l.append(rn.randint(1,100))
print(l)

sorted_list = [extractMin(l) for k in range(len(l))]
print(sorted_list)
```

The function `extractMin(..)` has time complexity of `O(n)` which is being called `n` times hence time complexity for entire sorting is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: This isn't bubble sort.  If you have 3, 1, 4, 2, then a single pass of bubble sort will turn this into 1, 3, 2, 4,  and the second pass will turn it into 1, 2, 3, 4.  The algorithm shown here is basically selection sort.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution which performs the sort purely using list comprehension.

```
import itertools
s = [5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_s = s[:]
temp1 = 0
final_data = [[globals().update(temp1=s[b]), globals().update(s=s[:b]+[temp1]+s[b+1:]), globals().update(s= s[:b]+[s[b+1]]+s[b+1:])] for i in range(len(s)) for b in range(len(s)-1) if s[b+1] < s[b]]
new_final_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[a]*new_s.count(a) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s)]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Convoluted solutions are usually accompanied by some kind of explanation.